# Laravel connect 2 different databases

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to connect in two differents databases, one mysql and other sql server

I got all the configuration and mysql works, sql server return nothing else but a white screen

Controller

```
Config::set('database.default', 'sqlsrv');

$teste = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getDatabaseName(); 

dd($teste);
```

database config

```
'default' => 'mysql',

'sqlsrv' => array(
           'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
                    'host'      => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                    'database'  => 'MP11_OFICIAL02',
                    'username'  => 'sa',
                    'password'  => 'asd',
           'prefix' => '',
          ),

'MG' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
            'port'      => '3306',
            'database'  => 'bd',
            'username'  => 'sistema',
            'password'  => 'asd',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            ),
```

and also if I dont change my 'default' => 'mysql' I get this error

could not find driver (View: /vagrant/app/views/usuarios/index.blade.php)

and if I change to sqlsrv just get a white screen

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL Server Native Client you are using? Please go to Control Panel >> Administrative Tools >> Data Sources (ODBC) and then click on the Drivers tab to find out which SQL Server Native Client you have already installed. Also please check your php.ini if you already install PDO driver for sqlsrv. Find 'PDO drivers' in php.ini. If you already install, you can see it will list like this. PDO Drivers => sqlsrv, mysqlsqlite

Comment: SQL native client 11.0 version 2011.110.3000.00
PDO I just have PDO obcd and mysql, how could I instal pdo for mssql ?

Comment: Download from this link. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098. Then follow this link how to include it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: But i'm using vagrant box with ubuntu for my project, its that what I'v to do ? thx!

Comment: I never used vagrant. So i cannot try it. But can you try refer this link.
http://blog.sea-of-dreams.com/connecting-php-to-ms-sql-server/